# Java can't add my total_value's to a new array with 100 slots

Tags: java

I have written made a program in Java that "walks" 500 random steps either back or forward (-1 or +1). The end steps (where it stops after 500 steps) is being printed to the console. I want these to be stored in a list where it'll tell me how many times the end step landed on, let's say -5. The end step needs to be looped 100 times:

```
public class RandomWalk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] y;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

            int[] x;
            x = new int[500];
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 500; i1++){
                 int L = (int) (Math.random()*2);
                 x[i1] = (L==0) ? -1 : 1;
            }
            int total_value = 0;
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 500; i1++)
                total_value += x[i1];

                System.out.println("Total: "+ total_value);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I query and return the result?

Comment: and what's wrong with this implementation??

Comment: Use an ArrayList? Or HashMap?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not completely sure how to do it @Alan Stokes

Comment: What do you "need help" with? Does this code not perform the way you want? looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. I've cleaned up the code some but more importantly I've added the HashMap totals and the usages of it.

```
package se.wederbrand.stackoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class RandomWalk {

    public static final int NBR_WALKS = 100;
    public static final int NBR_STEPS = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> totals = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = -NBR_STEPS; i <= NBR_STEPS; i++) {
            totals.put(i, 0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NBR_WALKS; i++) {
            int total_value = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < NBR_STEPS; j++) {
                int L = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                total_value += (L == 0) ? -1 : 1;
            }

            System.out.println("For run number " + i + " the total is " + total_value);
            totals.put(total_value, totals.get(total_value) + 1);
        }

        System.out.println("Number of times you ended on -5 " + totals.get(-5));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error using your code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

 at RandomWalk.main(RandomWalk.java:11)

Comment: @user2966573 - either upgrade to Java 1.7 or replace the `<>` with `<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: Right, sorry. My code is for Java7 but thats probably the only edit you need to make.

Comment: @Andreas WederBrand: EDIT: Sorry I realised how stupid that question was, I need it to tell me how many times it landed on each number ^^Thank you for the code

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand is it possible that the console output it'll say "It landed on 5 = 4 times, 4 = 0 times, 3 = 2 times 2..."?

Comment: Sure, instead of printing for -5 just iterate over totals.keySet() or something. (and either print or not print if the value is 0).

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand Ok what I did was I put it in a loop, said i = -100 and that i < 100 and then System.out.println("Number of times you ended on "+i+" = " + totals.get(i));

Comment: You need to from -500 to 500 as that is the edge case (only -1 or +1 steps). That is the same loop as I used to initialise the HashMap.

Comment: @Andreas Wederbrand is that really necessary? I mean isn't it rather unlikely to get over 100 +1's in a row?

Comment: It is very unlikely but not impossible. I changed the program some so instead of running 100 times it runs until the sum is outside -100 - +100. I then run it a couple of times and it took 12k runs up to 400k runs to find such a value.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ministry of Silly Walks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iV2ViNJFZC8) further recommends the following multi-threaded alternative:

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Test {

  private static final int NUMBER_WALKS = 100;
  private static final int NUMBER_STEPS = 500;

  private static class Counter implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicInteger counter;
    private final ConcurrentSkipListMap<Integer, Integer> totals;

    public Counter(final AtomicInteger counter, final ConcurrentSkipListMap<Integer, Integer> totals) {
      this.counter = counter;
      this.totals = totals;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      int result;
      Integer oldValue;

      while ((Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() == false) && (this.counter.decrementAndGet() >= 0)) {
        result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_STEPS; ++i) {
          result += ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        }

        oldValue = totals.putIfAbsent(result, 1);
        if (oldValue != null) {
          while (totals.replace(result, oldValue, oldValue + 1) == false) {
            oldValue = totals.get(result);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(NUMBER_WALKS);
    final ConcurrentSkipListMap<Integer, Integer> totals = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

    final int numCPUs = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numCPUs);

    for (int i = 0; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
      executor.submit(new Counter(counter, totals));
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    if (executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      for (Integer key : totals.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%3d was called %3d times.", key, totals.get(key)));
      }
    } else {
      executor.shutdownNow();
      System.err.println("Executor did not terminate as expected.");
    }
  }
}
```